# How to make textview that it should not write new characters once its filled up

Tags: android, layout

I have a textview that recieves user input. I would like that once the textview fills up with letters, that it should not place any more inside. What i have in my program now, is that although i cannot see the characters after the space is used up, the new letters are still being placed after the "...". It makes a big difference in my program and would like if someone can help me out thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

code:

```
Texview.setHint("whatever you want to say");
//code to do something else
button.setOnClickListener(new Button.onClickListener{
public void onClick(View v){
Textview.setEditable(false);
//more code if you want
}
});
```

hope this helps you, see ya

Comment: are you able to elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: check it out! if that helps you tell me if not tell me the mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can set `android:maxLength=""` in your TextView to limit the number of characters. You can also use `android:maxLines""` to limit the number of lines.

For example:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:maxLength="10"/>
```